# failing to run command as different user

Tags: python, linux, bash, quoting

trying to install pip inside a virtual env under a non root user called `jenkins`

when I ssh into the server and do this:

`sudo su jenkins
cd into relevant directory 
(autoenv kicks in and activates the virtual env)
pip install -r requirements.txt`

meaning it works.

But the startup scripts runs as root...

I've tried

su - jenkins -c "echo $(whoami) ;"
output : `root`

tried:

`sudo su jenkins &  "echo $(whoami) ;`

tried:

`sh my_bash.sh`

and `my_bash.sh`

`sudo su jenkins 
echo $(whoami)`

Comment: Don't forget to activate the virtualenv every time before using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
su - jenkins -c "echo $(whoami)"
```

by

```
su - jenkins -c 'echo $(whoami)'
```

to stop your shell executing `$(whoami)` as user root before running `su - jenkins echo root`.